# Unable to POST correctly in xlsx file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

The below is my excel file:

[image]

[image]

The below is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
let fileName='check3.xlsx'
var xlsx=require("xlsx");
 
app.route('/articles')

.post(function(req,res){
  console.log("added material "+ req.body.Material);
  var wb=xlsx.readFile(fileName,{cellDates:'true'});
  var ws=wb.Sheets["Sheet1"];
  //var data=xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
  var variable = xlsx.utils.decode_range(ws["!ref"])
  var newData=xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws,{header:0});
  var Origin='A'+ variable.e.r+1;
  rowNum=variable.e.r+1
  var flag=0;
  
  for(var i=1;i<=rowNum;i++){
    var x='A'+ i;
    
    if(ws[`${x}`].v == req.body.Material){
        console.log('Item already present');
        flag=1;
    }
  }
  if(flag===0){
    xlsx.utils.sheet_add_json(ws,
      [{
        Material: req.body.Material,
        price: parseInt(req.body.price),
        discount: parseInt(req.body.discount)
       }],
      {
       skipHeader:true,
       origin: Origin
      }
     );
     
     var newWB=xlsx.utils.book_new();
     var newWS=xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(newData);
     xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB,newWS,"Sheet1");
     xlsx.writeFile(newWB,fileName);  
  }
})
  

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

I have 2 issues:

1. Despite having a condition to check if the material already exists, I am able to add the material while the server is still running.
2. After adding the material for the second time, I get the following error:
   Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
   at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)